# DataGrip: Show full value in value editor

Tags: datagrip

In DataGrip (JetBrains), is there a way to show the full value in "Value Editor" ?

In my table, there's a column often contains large values (1~2MB) and I'd like to keep the cell preview in the table view capped (maybe 10 kb) so I can see the beginning part of the value. However, if I want to have the full value shown if I am viewing certain cell in the Value Editor so I can edit or copy the values.

I try setting the "Maximum number of bytes loaded per value" but it is setting both Value Editor and Preview in table, which cause performance issue. Is there any way I can just set the Value Editor to show the full value? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, you have to set it for every field.

1. Open the Datagrip settings by clicking on "File" -> "Settings" (or "Preferences" on Mac).
2. In the left-hand menu, navigate to "Database" -> "Data Editor and Viewer".
3. Find "Maximum number of bytes loaded per value" Modify that.

That should show the full value per field but it will consume more memory.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Yeah I am trying not to load every cell from that setting. It'd be great we have that ability, since I really like this tool.

Answer (score 0):

We have a feature request to implement this functionality. To stay updated on the progress, please follow it here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-17975